# python-Check if all elements in list1 are greater than eliments of the same index in list2

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
x = [50,25,30]
y = [25,30,50]
```

I am new to programming, how can I determine if x[0] >= y[0], x[1] >= x[1], with a loop or some other function?

I'd like to avoid the simple:

```
x[0] >= y[0]
x[1] >= y[1]
x[2] >= y[2]
```

as these lists may be appended.

Answer (score 2):

I renamed your lists to `list1` and `list2` respectively:

```
result = all(x >= y for x, y in zip(list1, list2))
```

Here `all(iterable)` checks whether *all* elements of `iterable` are *'truthy'*.

Answer (score 0):

My sollution will be based on the fact that the lenght of each list is the same.

```
if len(x) == len(y):
    test_container = 0   #will store the number of trues
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] > y[i]:
            test_container += 1
    if test_container == len(x):
        print("All elements in x are bigger than the correspondent in y")
    else:
        print("False")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = True
for xi, yi in zip(x, y):
    if xi < yi:
        result = False
        break
```

***result*** will contain the answer.

If you want to do it as a function:

```
def compare(x, y):
    for xi, yi in zip(x, y):
        if xi < yi:
            return False
    return True
```